# report argument of pivta() function not working [R Shiny]

Tags: r, shiny, webdatarocks

I am trying to point to a report, which is saved in sharepoint, to the pivta() function in R Shiny application through the report argument of pivta() function.
But its somehow not working for me.
Can anyone here guide me how to do that ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: shiny doesn't have a function called `pivta`, please provide more details and your code, read [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of opening an issue on the `pivta` GitHub: https://github.com/feddelegrand7/pivta/issues ? Maybe you can get some help from the author of the library.